# Vmware - Can access web via IP but not via domain

Tags: ip, domain

I have Windows 7 as host and Windows xp as guest. Host connected to the internet via wifi. Internet access on the host running normally, and on the guest can't access via domain, but can via IP.

I've tried to flush dns on guest and machine, but not work. Have solution?

Answer (score 0):

Is the guest machine using NAT or bridge connection ?

Is DNS added/configured on the guest machine ?
If not, add your either your DNS or an open DNS address. That would be the easiest way to fix this.

Comment: I changed guest machine  from NAT to bridge connection but it still does not work. how way to add DNS?

Comment: Did you manually add a DNS to the guest ? Run a command prompt, ipconfig /all and check what DNS is listed there. Check again after you manually add one (let IP via DHCP and only enable manual DNS).

Comment: I run the software proxifier, and didn't configuration manually
http://i.imgur.com/AHZJGrH.png

Comment: Your DNS is given by host, and here a lot of things can go wrong. Just go to the local area connection properties (of the guest), TCP/IPv4, and 'use following DNS' 208.67.222.222
208.67.220.220
Those are openDNS that should work from anywhere. If it does not work like this, it means something the host OS is blocking traffic and in that case further investigations will be needed.